# Tagging an SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging, sql-server-2012, request

I would like to be able to tag an SQL query somehow, so I can relate the query execution to the web request that triggered the query. I already have a unique request id, that I tag my logs and other monitoring with, so I can easily do a complete trace across the weblogs and new relic for example.

But when I look at a report of long running SQL queries for example, I cannot trace that back to the request that triggered the SQL Query. I would really like to be able to tag the query with my request id somehow.

I can't find anything online. When I search I just find blogs about storing tags and tag clouds in SQL. Not really what I need.

Hope the question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting post...

I hope, adding an extra nullable parameter to your stored procedure(s) will ensure that the profiler will catch the unique id passed during a call (in the trace) whether you use that parameter inside the procedure or not (i.e. to do something meaningful...like inserting into an audit table with unique id, procedure name, timestamp etc).
But I think that will make life difficult as you now have to update all your procedures.

If you already have logging turned on (web server) and it captures the same unique id in its request (log file) along with a timestamp then you probably can code a small utility app that reads the log file and find matching entries in the traced table by the timestamp alone.
The only thing that might go wrong is if your web server and database server have differeing times (you need to offset your calculation accordingly).

I don't know if this will help but it is certainly a very interesting project and I am hoping somebody have experienced this thing and came up with a nice solution.
Will be closely watching this post if such a solution exists....

All the best...

Comment: Hmmm... not all access is done through stored procedures. In fact this is an old legacy system with thousands of queries and some are generated dynamically. The one step that I can think of right now, that would be easy to hook into, is when the connection string is fetched. Can I add extra meta data to the connection string?

Comment: I don't know if the underlying provider will parse that extra info...but You can certainly use a Decorator pattern to inherit from SqlClient and add custom properties to it to uniquely identify the connection and use this specialized class instead of SqlClient...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to follow up the query execution in Activity Monitor. But have you considered using a DMV or SQL PROFILER ?

In my opinion, your best bet would be to wrap it in a stored proc. This way you will be able to FILTER your trace only for this object. Here's an example of a simple select and the same select wrapped in stored proc named sproc1 :

[image]

As you can see in this image, you can start a SQL PROFILER trace and filter it on the ObjectName. You can then add other column like CPU, StartTime, ...

If you can't use a stored proc, then I would suggest to insert a comment before the exec like this:

```
/* ID1234 */ 
select * from table1
```

Then use SQL PROFILER the same way but you now filter on the TextData using your ID

[image]

Here the result :

[image]

Comment: Hi PollusB, Using the profiler is something I would do when the query has been identified. Right now I just need to identify a query and match it to a web request.

Comment: Tell me more about the web request. Tell  me more about what you do actually or plan to do actually step by step so I can tailor my answer. Can you change the source code ?